# cant use apt-update anymore

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, apt, raspbian

I can no longer use apt-get update at all. And often I can't install anything anymore. Every time I use ap-get update I get this output

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Ign:3 https://download.docker.com jessie InRelease
Ign:4 https://download.docker.com jessie Release
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com jessie/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com jessie/main all Packages
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com jessie/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com jessie/main all Packages
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com jessie/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com jessie/main all Packages
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com jessie/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com jessie/main all Packages
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com jessie/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com jessie/main all Packages
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com jessie/main armhf Packages
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com jessie/main all Packages
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en
Err:5 https://download.docker.com jessie/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:21c7:b000:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com jessie/main all Packages
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com jessie/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:21c7:b000:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried to remove the docker repositories. I was able to remove some of it but now I can't get any further :(

Does anyone know what to do?

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that https://download.docker.com/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages (the URL repository your computer has) returned me an error 404 as well, and after a bit of searching found out https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/jessie/stable/binary-armhf/ resolves well. So my opinion is that Docker has moved its repositories to some other directory. This can be solved by editing the URL to fetch the packages.

Try adding this line on `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/jessie/stable/binary-armhf jessie devel admin
```

and comment the line which should look something like this:

```
deb https://download.docker.com/dists/jessie/stable/binary-armhf jessie devel admin
```

(note the second line doesn't contain `linux/debian/`)

Comment: Why add it on top? These are usually appended at the bottom.

Comment: @gronostaj True. It doesn't really matter where OP should add this line. Editing that.

Comment: Thank you it worked :)